# Is there a way to password protect an assemble.io website?

Tags: javascript, html, assemble

I'm looking for a way to restrict access and password protect an assemble.io website.

The idea is to mimic a web application authorization where there is a login form with user/password fields. In this case there would be just one user and password. The member would login and gai. Access to the restricted area of the application and be able to view/browse beyond the login area.

Being a static website, I want to avoid .htacess basic authentication. Is there a way to do this in assemble? Using pure js or something else which would provide a basic authentication for static websites?

I was imagining sending the user and password to an external API and if there are valid the user is redirected to the restricted area. Don't know how it would deal with the session in this case but maybe there's a js way to deal with them.

Comment: Can you describe the security scenario? If you are making a Single-Page Application, you can use a token-based authentication service to control web service calls like [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) or [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com/).  Other than that, static web sites don't have security separate from a server.

Comment: I've expanded the security scenario

Comment: I can think of several, but you're asking for a product recommendation which makes it off-topic for Stackoverflow.

Comment: I can accept a no product solution. I'll update the question

Comment: use .htaccess and .htpasswd for http basic authentification